# Array formula with another array as input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a dynamic range to use on dropdown lists in excel, I was not able to use the traditional solutions as I'll have several lines where I need this validation, and that would need me to create a "buffer" column for each entry and I want to avoid that.

Here's my Data table:

| Item | Vendor |
| --- | --- |
| B123 | A |
| B123 | B |
| B321 | C |
| B321 | D |
| B456 | E |

This starts in cell A1 and is formmated as a Table called ItemList.

Then I have the following formula on cell D1. My output is a horizontal list with the unique entries of the Item column

`=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(ItemList[ITEM]))`

Then on cell D2 I have the below:
`=FILTER(ItemList[Vendor];ItemList[ITEM]=D1)`

Which is then expanding the values A & B below B123. However I'd like it to also work on all the spilled range of D1.

This is my current output:

| B123 | B321 | B456 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  |
| B |  |  |

This is my desired output:

| B123 | B321 | B456 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | E |
| B | D |  |

Any ideas? I tried adding D1# instead of D1 in D2 formula, but no good.

Comment: It will need to be dragged over.  You can use `=IF(D1<>"";FILTER(ItemList[Vendor];ItemList[ITEM]=D1);"")` but you will need to drag if further than you would ever need.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for the reply. That's what I'm trying to avoid as the ranges are going to vary a lot since the inital data comes from a PowerQuery. Any ideas maybe using different approach?

Comment: You could use power query to do the classification, but I do not use it that much so I cannot help.